# Navbar doesnt show toggle button and its links

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Even though this subject has been approached multiple times on SO, after I have read a lot of these answers I still can't seem to figure out why my toggle button is not being rendered properly (I can find it in the console in the browser but is not visible and when I click it doesn't drop-down).

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top" s>
    
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" ></a>
      
      <button class="navbar-toggler "
       type="button" 
       data-toggle="collapse" 
       data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" 
       aria-controls="#navbarNavDropdown" 
       aria-expanded="true" 
       aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" ">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Store</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
    
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I hope this is better! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: TJ was asking for you to use the Stackoverflow [snippet tool](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that would include links to CDN versions of the Bootstrap CSS and JS and jQuery that you're using, and not just your HTML code. You're using the bootstrap-4 tag, but you use glyphicon icons, which are from Bootstrap 3. Without a running example of your problem, it's hard to evaluate what's happening.

Comment: I hope is better now, sorry for that...

Comment: There's no JavaScript here - presumably that's where the error is. Can you add it?

Comment: Yess!! Thank you so much robin! Been busting my brains on this for some time.. Thanks again!